# Script To Show Specified Layers in Photoshop(JSX)

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

I'm trying to write a script that toggles the specific layers that I enter into a prompt window, but I keep getting "namesArray.indexOf is not a function". Here is the code-

```
// Prompt the user for comma-separated layer names
var layerNames = prompt("Enter layer names separated by commas:");

// Convert the input string into an array of names
var namesArray = layerNames.split(",");

// Loop through all layers in the document
for (var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.layers.length; i++) {
  var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[i];

  // Toggle visibility for layers with matching names
  if (namesArray.indexOf(layer.name) >= 0) {
    layer.visible = !layer.visible;
  }
}
```

How do I go about fixing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Photoshop's version of indexOf only works on strings - it doesn't work on your array. I get the same error. I can only think that the version of ECMA script that Photoshop uses is so antique that the above is true. See [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/searching-arrays-indexof/m-p/5518813) for more details.

A quick workaround is to add a function that does the same trick:

```
// Prompt the user for comma-separated layer names
var layerNames = prompt("Enter layer names separated by commas:");

// Convert the input string into an array of names
var namesArray = layerNames.split(",");

// Loop through all layers in the document
for (var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.layers.length; i++)
{
  var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[i];

  var idx = get_index(namesArray, layer.name);

  // Toggle visibility for layers with matching names
  // if (namesArray.indexOf(layer.name) >= 0) 
  if (idx >= 0) 
  {
    layer.visible = !layer.visible;
  }
}


function get_index(arr, str)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    if (arr[i] == str) return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there also a way to make this work for layers that are grouped separately?

Comment: To do stuff with groups is a bit more complex... Here's a way of looping over all layers including groups. Look at my [question and answer here]. You should be able to work it out from there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697222/how-do-i-loop-over-all-layers-including-groups-in-photoshop/75697223#75697223)