# How do I loop over all layers including groups in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop-script

I can loop all the layers in a Photoshop document with

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

// main loop
for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--)    
{
  var thisLayer = srcDoc.layers[i];
}
```

But how to do this with groups?

Answer (score 0):

To loop over groups you need a recursive function:

```
// group layer vegetables
var theLayers = collectAllLayers(app.activeDocument, 0);


// function collect all layers
function collectAllLayers (theParent, level)
{
   for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0; m--)
   {
      var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];
      if (theLayer.typename == "ArtLayer")
      {

         // do stuff here for art layers
      }
      else
      {
         collectAllLayers(theLayer, level + 1)
      }
   }
}
```